# Python 3.3.2 - How to Set Out a Small Database?

Tags: database, python-3.x

I am creating a small database for 'trial', per se. I have tried a few setting outs (`[{key: value}, {key: value}]`. But, I need a solution that can be called by an ID (12345), a name (Rob Alsod), an area (A4 (Like an apartment building)), or a job (Manager, Administrator, etc). So, something like a dictionary (which can only be called by *one* key) will not work. I tried making a 'Person' class, but I need a way to easily keep track of the classes, and also to assign them easily. For example,

```
for whatever in whatever:
    what = Person(name = 'Rob Alsod', id = 12345, job = 'Admin', area = 'A1')   # What can I make this iterate with? (Badly formed question)
```

My point is, as it loops through, I cannot assign it to the same thing again and again.

Could someone try to make sense of what I am saying, and suggest a way to format my database?

Comment: the question is not clear? please add what you want? why do you want the loop?>?

Comment: @suhail The point of the loop is to assign a Person() to a variable. The only problem is: I have no idea how the variable can change as it loops.

Comment: you can use list. for eg:`what=[]` now inside loop `what.append(Person(name=......))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use SQLAlchemy with SQLite. SQL queries are only a few lines of code away:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
db = create_engine('sqlite:///people.db')

metadata = MetaData()

user = Table('people', metadata,
Column('ID', Integer, primary_key = True),
Column('name', String(16), nullable = False),
Column('area', String(16)),
Column('job', String(60))
)
```

After that it is easy `connection = db.connect(); result = connection.execute("select ID from people")`

On Linux, pip and apt-get make the install a breeze as well.
HTH, Phil

Comment: This looks like just what I need. Could you perhaps explain each part of the code? In specific, the String(x) part of the code. (Sorry, my phone doesn't have backticks).

Comment: @Rob Alsod - The `create_engine` statement creates a Dialect object tailored for SQLite, while an actual connection is initiated with `db.connect()`. `MetaData` is a container object that keeps information about the db. `String` is the SQL equivalent of VARCHAR. See the doc (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want small database for storing any objects identified by key you can use `shelve` module:

http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/shelve.html